# Display CustomError message and status code thrown from server in HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core API server with an Angular client. I want the client to be able to catch the exception thrown from the server. I use an HTTP Interceptor to handle errors in Angular but this returns:

> 500 Internal Server Error

to the client side in `HttpErrorResponse`.

I want it to return my custom exception message. Why isn't the `HttpErrorResponse` catching the `CustomException` thrown?

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import {  of } from "rxjs";
import { tap} from "rxjs/operators";
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import {
HttpEvent,
HttpInterceptor,
HttpHandler,
HttpRequest,
HttpResponse,
HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        if (err.error instanceof Error) {

          console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);

        } 
        else {

          console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body 
       was: ${err.error}`);

        }


        return Observable.empty();
      });
  }
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Angular. If you want your server to return a response with a specific status code and a specific error message, then what matters is the server code (and technology). If you want to know what your server sends as a response now, open your browser dev tools, go to the network panel, and inspec the response header and body.

Comment: I check response in  network .it return my throw exception message and status from server but i can  get it in HttpInterceptor .catch

Comment: Read the answer you got. You're not using operators correctly.

Comment: thanks  a lot . you are right  .i  get my  throw message  from err.error.Message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `catchError` operator in order to alter the error and throw it.

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    let data = {};
    // Here you can set a different object to be returned if you want
    // if you need it only for specific status command, you can check for error.status
    data = {
      reason: error && error.error && error.error.reason ? error.error.reason : '',
      status: error.status
    };
    return throwError(error);
  }));
```

You can check more in [vigneshsithirai's repo](https://github.com/vigneshsithirai/Angular-Interceptor/blob/master/src/app/interceptor/httpconfig.interceptor.ts).